# JavaScript hide and show content

Tags: javascript, css, dom-events

I was searching for a pure CSS answer to hiding and showing content but after no luck I have been playing around with a piece of JavaScript code. My question is below the code, as it may help you to see the code first.

```
      <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.text_container').addClass("visible");

        $('.text_container').click(function() {
            var $this = $(this);
            if ($this.hasClass("visible")) {
                    $(this).removeClass("visible").addClass("hidden");
            } else {
                    $(this).removeClass("hidden").addClass("visible");
            }
        });
    });
   </script>  


        <div id="services" class="text_container"> 
         <h4>SERVICES</h4>
             <div>
              <p>Loads of text blah blah blah</p>
             </div>
         </div>


         /* HIDE and SHOW content JavaScript function */
  .hidden div {display:none;}
  .visible div {display:block;} 

  .text_container {
      background-color: #39b54a;
     background-image: url("pattern2.png");
     border: 1px solid #777777;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px  inset, 0 0 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) inset, 0 16px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4) inset, 0 4px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    color: #000000;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: left;
    width: auto;

  }
  .text_container h4 {
     cursor: pointer;
  }
  .text_container div p {
      margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
  .visible > div {
   display: block;
   font-size: 17px;
    height: 100%;
  }

  #rating > div {
    clear: left;
    height: 260px;
  }
  /* end of HIDE and SHOW content javascript function */
```

Currently as expected the div with class = text_container area is clickable, so if a place a form in the child DIV when you select the form the content hides.  I Would like to make only the H4 element
clickable so clicking on the shown content will not hide the content.

I am useless at JavaScript and I imagine this requires rejigging the js.

Comment: I've put an answer up, but actually now I'm not sure I know what you want to acheive. When you click the h4 element, what do you want to happen? Do you want the content div to disappear when you click on the `h4` element and then reappear again?

Comment: Yeah exactly as you thought. Only when i test it, it requires 2 clicks to show content from page refresh for each expanding div.  AM guessing one to select and one to expand.  Users can just double click to open and from then on 1 click open or close, fiddley but thats alright. Thanks again

Comment: I don't know why it's doing that Renai. If you have a look at this JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/wNJx8/ it seems to be working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
$('.text_container h4').click(function() {
    if($(this).hasClass("visible")) {
        $(this).removeClass("visible").addClass("hidden");
    } else {
        $(this).removeClass("hidden").addClass("visible");
    }
});
```

The content in the $(' ... ') is just like a CSS selector, so if you know CSS then it won't be a problem for you.

With CSS you could style that h4 element with:

```
.text_container h4 { color: #000000; }
```

and just the same, you can create a wrapped set with jQuery that selects it with:

```
$('.text_container h4')
```

Answer (score 1):

This will accomplish your goal, [**example**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZW3Py/2/):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.text_container h4').addClass("visible");

    $('.text_container h4').click(function() {
        var $this = $(this).parent();
        if ($this.hasClass("visible")) {
            $this.removeClass("visible").addClass("hidden");
        } else {
            $this.removeClass("hidden").addClass("visible");
        }
    });
});
```

We are selecting the H4 and adding the click event to it, but then using [**.parent()**](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) to access to parent DIV.

Comment: Works almost perfect, one slight issue i found, in Firefox, on page load if you select the H4 element contents in that DIV scale up slightly and it requires a second click to show the content, although once opened, hide and show works perfectly. I have more than one .text_container class being the parent of the H4, but each with different id's on the div containing class. Gonna have a fiddle with it see if its something in my css. apart from that, it works great, thanks :)

Comment: sorted the raise in type size, but in firefox the h4 element requires 2 clicks to show content then works perfect :s

Answer (score 0):

replace `$('.text_container')...` with `$('.text_container h4')...` or, better yet, `$('h4')....` if it's the only H4 element on the page.

Answer (score 0):

change this:

```
      $('.text_container').click(function() {
```

to this:

```
      $('.text_container h4').click(function() {
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply replace with

```
$('.text_container h4').click( ...
```

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure how someone will be able to click on an element with `display: none`. Also, replace this:

```
if ($this.hasClass("visible")) {
    $(this).removeClass("visible").addClass("hidden");
} else {
    $(this).removeClass("hidden").addClass("visible");
}
```

With this:

```
$(this).toggle();
```

Full code:

```
$(function() {
    $('.text_container h4').click(function() {
        $(this).parent().toggle(); // toggles between visible and hidden
    });
});
```